# XML parser configured does not prevent nor limit external entities resolution

Tags: java, xml, error-handling, fortify

I get all the way everytime again this error even though I changed my code to what I found in the web to this following:

```
private Document convertInputToDocument(InputStream xml) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason behind this is/was that the fortify scan doesn't compile those packages which are used and therefore can't see that we provide enough security!